# Weka java.io.IOException Error while loading Arff file

Tags: csv, weka, java-io, arff

I get error while loading Arff file, and when i load the csv file and click "visualize all", nothing can be visualized and the screen gives "Too many values to display". Here is the error while loading Arff file:

[Error while loading Arff file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9B8Z.png)

Comment: Seems like you have not declared any attributes.Try to use the format defined here : http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Answer (score 0):

For your first error you need to declare attributes for the arff file as defined here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

Your second error states that there is no @relation defined so you need to add it above your attributes declaration as shown in the link above.

So you need to add the following line:

```
@relation yourRelationName
```